# MySQL JOINED table query that adds a Count() column returns 1 when zero match

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mariadb

```
SELECT sg.date, sg.groupName, sg.highlights, user.display_name as displayName,
        COUNT(*) as cmtcnt
        FROM `saved_groups` as sg
        LEFT JOIN `user` on user.email = sg.userName
        LEFT JOIN `user_comments` as uc on sg.groupName = uc.groupName
        GROUP BY sg.groupName
```

I have two tables, `saved_groups` and `user_comments` and the second line of the query should (does, it works) return an extra column with the number of comments associated with each group.

However, when a group has zero comments associated with it, the count returns 1 when it should return zero.

How can I fix this query?

I tried: `COUNT(*)-1 as cmtcnt` -- and that returns zero for the groups without comments, but it also returns an incorrect number (-1) for groups that have associated comments.

I also tried: `NULL(Count(*), 0)` -- but that errors out with `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`

I also tried: `COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) as cmtcnt` -- and that made no difference whatsoever (returned 1 for all groups with zero comments, correct number for the others)

Suggestions?

Comment: Generally, it is a good idea to post the structure of the involved tables and some sample data. https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is also a good resource for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT()` aggregate function never returns `null` and `COUNT(*)` always returns a value greater than `0` because it counts all the rows of the resultset.

What you want is to count the rows of `user_comments` that match the conditions in the `ON` clause and you can do this by specifying inside the parentheses the column `groupName`:

```
COUNT(uc.groupName)
```

This way only non-null rows will be counted and you can get `0` if for a specific `sg.groupName` there is no matching row in `user_comments`.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting all things from all tables when you say count(*).
Because `saved_groups` has a row, you get the 1 returned, which is correct.

What you want is to only count the comments. So instead of `COUNT(*) as cmtcnt` you should use `COUNT(uc.*) as cmtcnt`.

This tells the query to only count rows from the uc table.